# Site shows URL instead of "meta title" after deleted few plugins (not any SEO plugin was deleted)

Tags: plugins, title, seo, blog-page

www.Pifeed.net

after i deleted some useless plugins due to load-time issues the blog pages show url instead of title tag, though meta title tag is there in source code..

thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your title tag is inside the script tag. It must be placed outside script.  So you have to close the script tag for "adsbygoogle".